# The command gulp serve don't work

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts

when i get up my local server with the command(gulp serve), instead the show in the browser my first web part it create a files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order work it properly make sure gulpfile.js contain the proper code.

- gulpfile.js  should contain following code.

```
'use strict';

const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');

build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`);

var getTasks = build.rig.getTasks;
build.rig.getTasks = function () {
  var result = getTasks.call(build.rig);

  result.set('serve', result.get('serve-deprecated'));

  return result;
};

build.initialize(require('gulp'));
```

- package.json file should contain following script.

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "gulp bundle",
    "clean": "gulp clean",
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
```